# Sort out words that dont have these letters, Python

Tags: python, sorting

### Trying to sort out words that do not have the yellow letters (yl).
currently it doesn't require them to have both... I need it to have both
get it to print just [again]

-0
-'g','i','n'
-'o','e','l'

```
import sys
import time
#list of words that are available
list0 = [
  'again',
  'alone',
  'align',
]
cq = 0
s1 = ''
l1 = 0
dw = ''
yl = ''

print("it's location is -1 to -5 (last to first) or 0 to 4 (first to last)")
print("grey letter format is - '_','_', for every grey letter")

if cq == 0:
    s1 = input('what is the green letter?; ')
    print()
    time.sleep(2)
    l1 = input('where is ' + s1 + '?; ')
    print()
    time.sleep(2)
    yl = input('what letters are yellow?; ')
    print()
    time.sleep
    dw = input('what letters are grey?; ')
    print()
    cq += 1

print("Searching.")
time.sleep(1)
print("Searching..")
time.sleep(1)
print("Searching...")
time.sleep(1)
print()
#letters that can't be used
deadletters = 'm'


list1 = [w for w in list0 if (any(set(w) & set(yl)))]
#sorts out words with dead letters
list2 = [w for w in list1 if not (any(set(w) & set(dw)))]

#only lets words with "a___y" through
found = [w for w in list2 if (w[int(l1)] == s1)]

print()
print(found)
```

Having Fun Playing Wordle...
don't worry about me...
i need more words cause i have too much code...
:)...

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. Please clarify.

Comment: Im trying to sort out all  words that don't have all the (yl) letters

Comment: Yes. I agree with John. You should tell us what you tried and what worked and what didn't work. Or insert some print statements and explain why something worked differently than what you expected. Or in simpler terms, as John said, please be more specific on your issue.

Comment: it prints words that don't have all the yl letters

Comment: Wordle brute force?

Comment: no it's just to narrow down the amount of words to guess.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "sort out"

Comment: ignore them, or dont print them in found